# Horizontally scroll a text-based/console program

Tags: command-line, console, console-application

I am trying to use TestDisk (partition and file recovery program) to recover some files that I have lost. TestDisk runs as a text-based/console program and prints a long list of deleted files, one per line. Each file is listed as it's path and because I am running this from a rescue live linux cd, I am limited to a 80 character console.

I need to go though this list of files a select the ones I want to be undeleted, however I can only see the start of each path and..

```
...cuments and Settings\kin
...cuments and Settings\kin
...cuments and Settings\kin
```

...doesn't give me much information to go on (this list is probably over a hundred entries long).

I have been thinking about running TestDisk inside a screen session and hopefully increase the virtual terminal width and then simple scroll horizontally to the right. But screen doesn't seem to support something like this.

Is there anything that does?

I should clarify that TestDisk is a interactive console program. Thus I can not take the output and parse it with something else. Additionally I need the interactivity because when I find the files I want to undelete I need to select then inside TestDisk and then proceed to the next step in TestDisk.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll lock?

Answer (score 1):

Run the output through emacs.  Then you can have all the functionality you want!